# wm_message sound device changed notification

Tags: c#

i have a pci card installed on my machine.
The pci card acts like a sound card and iam using it to stream audio files.
This card has the ability to act like a stereo sound card or a 5.1 sound card.

The Pci card has a small tool that can change between those 2 modes.
Whenever i change from 2.0 to 5.1, i get a wm_devicechanged event.
But this is not very efficent since i get this wm_message whenever i inserted a usb as example or if i just disconnect a usb cable.

I need to catch the changes that occurs only to the sound device itself.
Is there a way to get out which device has been changed ?
My device appears under the Sound, Video and game controllers in Windows Device Manager.
And looking in the property page of my device i found out it has the following Device class guid

```
{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
```

which applies to the mentioned catagory above.

So i need a way to "Watch" this device for changes, and skip the "deviceChanged" messages that doesnot belong to this device.

Any help is really appreciated.

p.s.: iam not working with usb devices. it is a pci card plugged into my pc

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the messages being sent.  If changing the configuration results in a [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480.aspx) message with a [`DBT_DEVICE_ARRIVAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363205.aspx) parameter then you can potentially read the device GUID from the [`DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363244.aspx) structure that is passed with the message.